# MongoDB and constructors/classes in node.js (async)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript

I want to abstract certain MongoDB queries/documents using classes.

Basically I think the way is to somewhere (an own class?) create the connection and use this connection(pool) in various Classes. But how would I do this code-wise. For example I am not sure, when I use a  MongoDBConnectionClass and initialize the connection in the constructor how to make sure I wait for the connection to be established to continue using it somewhere else.

I think I am doing something wrong here. Here a schema to maybe better understand what I mean

```
MongoDBConnection(Class?)
+---- Class1+ # eg. Book
+---- Class2+ # eg. Library
+---- Class3+ # eg. Dust
            |
            +-- Library1+ # eg. New Book Release
            +-- Library2+ # ...
            +-- Library3+ # ...
                        |
                        +-- App1
                        +-- App2
                        +-- App3
```

Oh an CoffeScript answers would be great, but JS of course works as well.

Comment: Everything is event-driven in Node. Have you looked at [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/index.html)? I'd suggest starting with it and maybe some NodeJS tutorials.

Comment: I know, everything is event driven. I just wonder what's a good pattern to handle this.

Comment: You're going to need to provide some more detail about your problem. What's your code look like? The obvious answer is to just delay other work until the connection is available. So, it's not clear what issue you're having.

Comment: As I stated. I want to reach abstraction, like described above and am not sure how to do it without adding too much complexity. Delaying work sounds like a queue. Another way would be to like put the whole application into db.open. Another way would be to separate the constructor of a class from a .connect() method.

Comment: Basically, I like to know what patterns there to separate glue and business code.

Comment: You haven't said how it will be used (web pages, services, an export tool, etc.). Are you using Express with Node? Or some other framework? Are you using mongoose?

Comment: I am using the native mongodb driver and what I meant with this diagram is that I basically want to have these classes which are either collections or even about individual documents. The libraries are operations that use these classes and the apps are basically various frontends/views, that currently are long running web services/rest interfaces. I want to refactor things a bit, cause somewhere between the libaries and the apps there is going to be something to handle distributed instances (be it process or async functions, not sure yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this pattern in my tutorial (will be out soon)

https://github.com/christkv/tic-tac-toe-steps

If you look at the model and controllers I wrap the actual function with the db object.